# Grails 2.4.3 + Neo4j Plugin = No bean named 'sessionFactory'

Tags: grails, groovy, intellij-idea

I want to create a sample app in Grails with Neo4J. (on IntelliJ)

After creating a simple app and added the necessary configurations inside Buildconfig.groovy

**Repo**

```
mavenRepo 'http://m2.neo4j.org/content/repositories/releases/'
```

**Plugin**

```
    compile ":neo4j:2.0.0-M02"
```

I want to use MySql and Neo4J at the same time (adding mapping inside the domain model, when I want neo4j).

But I have this error:

```
 Error |
2014-12-14 19:05:59,261 [localhost-startStop-1] ERROR context.GrailsContextLoaderListener  - Error initializing the application: No bean named 'sessionFactory' is defined
Message: No bean named 'sessionFactory' is defined
    Line | Method
->>  104 | postProcessBeanFactory in org.grails.datastore.gorm.plugin.support.PersistenceContextInterceptorAggregator
```

What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: I don't know much about grails/java, but are you using neo4j 2.0.0?  I think that's a relatively old version, so I don't know if there would be any compatibility issues...

Comment: 2.0.0 is the version of the Neo4j Grails plugin

Comment: Ah, carry on then ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found a solution: Do not use this plugin. I prefer to use a micro service architecture. I created an application with Spring Boot, Groovy and Neo4J. I omitted controllers, model and spring repositories.

**build.gradle**

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:1.2.2.RELEASE")
    }
}


apply plugin: 'groovy'
apply plugin: 'idea'
apply plugin: 'spring-boot'


jar {
    baseName = "it.luis"
    version = '0.1-SNAPSHOT'
}



repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    jcenter()
    maven { url "http://m2.neo4j.org/content/repositories/releases/" }
    maven { url "https://repo.spring.io/libs-release" }
}

dependencies {
//    compile 'org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-all:2.4.0'
    compile localGroovy()
    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web")
    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter")
    compile("org.springframework:spring-context")
    compile("org.springframework:spring-tx")
    compile("org.springframework.data:spring-data-neo4j")
    compile("org.hibernate:hibernate-validator")
    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator")
    compile("javax.el:javax.el-api:2.2.4")
    testCompile("junit:junit")

    /* Swagger */
    compile "com.mangofactory:swagger-springmvc:0.9.5"

    /* Stormpath */
    compile "org.sonatype.oss:stormpath-spring-security"
    runtime "com.stormpath.sdk:stormpath-sdk-httpclient:0.9.3"
}
```

**Application.groovy**

```
package it.luis

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.EnableAutoConfiguration
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication
/**
 * Created by Luigi on 01/03/2015.
 */
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableAutoConfiguration
class Application {



    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class,args)


    }
}
```

**Neo4JConf.groovy**

```
package it.luis


import com.mangofactory.swagger.plugin.EnableSwagger
import org.neo4j.graphdb.GraphDatabaseService
import org.neo4j.graphdb.factory.GraphDatabaseFactory
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration
import org.springframework.data.neo4j.config.EnableNeo4jRepositories
import org.springframework.data.neo4j.config.Neo4jConfiguration
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.EnableWebMvc

/**

 */
@Configuration
@EnableNeo4jRepositories(basePackages = "it.luis")
@ComponentScan("it.luis")
@EnableWebMvc
@EnableSwagger
class EngineConfiguration extends Neo4jConfiguration {


    EngineConfiguration() {
        setBasePackage("it.luis")
    }

    @Bean
    GraphDatabaseService graphDatabaseService() {
        return new GraphDatabaseFactory().newEmbeddedDatabase("neo4j.db");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

having same problem - if I removed the neo4j plugin - and create an ordinary domain class+test works fine

as soon as you enable the neo4j plugin (2.0.0-M2) - and run the same test again it fails with the errors above -

no idea how enabling the neo plugin removed the sessionFactory bean that grails normally setsup

something cooky going on

Comment: In these conditions: https://github.com/neo4j-contrib/java-rest-binding or this http://projects.spring.io/spring-data-neo4j/. I will keep you updated!

Answer (score 0):

tried to cheat and added this to the resources.groovy beans

```
...
sessionFactory(ConfigurableLocalSessionFactoryBean) {
    dataSource = ref('dataSource')
    hibernateProperties = ["hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto": "create-drop",
                           "hibernate.show_sql":     "true"]
}
```

and tried to re run the test - still fails as it says that in error

```
..Message: No such property: ConfigurableLocalSessionFactoryBean for class: resources
```

so its somewhere deep in the bowels...